# Use the output of a command as input to the same command in a loop

Tags: bash, shell-script, template

So I'm trying to find a template for bash/shell script that essentially run a command, let's call it "command1" using an input "X" and then use the output of command1 on itself...but in a loop.

Here a real world example:

```
echo "hello" | cut -c2-
```

which will remove the first character at the beginning of the input string and output:

```
ello
```

Now, the above is just an example to illustrate the template mentioned above. Following this example, how could i use *command1* output:

```
echo "hello" | cut -c2-
```

But as input, in a loop, either indefinite loop or until only one byte/character remain.

So that i don't need to copy/paste the output and replace it with the old input:

```
echo "ello" | cut -c2-
```

Or need to use multiple pipe which would be too slow/inefficient.

**Simpler Explanation**

Using manual action, this would be the replacement of me(the user) copy pasting the output of the command i gave as example (or the pseudo code i described earlier) and use that as input for that same command, repeating that same action until "one" byte or char remain.

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried?

Comment: not homework (not in school since a couple years now). This is just for a couple projects/experiment which would be offtopic to this post :) (which is why i called it a template, given i can use this in different ways and contexts) @NasirRiley

Comment: What would the final output be of your code?

Comment: Please give a pseudo-code example of this loop, I am having a lot of trouble understanding what you mean. You're not just looking for `command | while read line; do echo "$line"; done` are you? What would this loop be looping over?

Comment: Essentially one byte/character :) @Kusalananda

Comment: Well, in simple/manual description, this would be the remplacement of me(the user) copy pasting the output of the command i gave as example (or the pseudo code i described earlier) and use that as *input* for that same command, repeating that same action until "one" byte or char remain. :D @terdon

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add that since it clarifies your request significantly.

Comment: Done :D do feel free to tell me if this need better editing beside this @terdon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for something like this:

```
$ var=hello
$ while [ -n "$var" ]; do 
    printf -- "Var is now '%s'\n" "$var"
    var=$(printf -- '%s\n' "$var" | cut -c2-); 
done
Var is now 'hello'
Var is now 'ello'
Var is now 'llo'
Var is now 'lo'
Var is now 'o'
```

Answer (score 7):

That actually works *on Linux*:

```
echo hello | tee /dev/fd/0
hello
hello
hello
...

echo hello | gawk '!length{exit(0)} {print; print substr($0,2) >"/dev/fd/3"; fflush()}' 3>/dev/fd/0
hello
ello
llo
lo
o
```

That takes advantage of the fact that on Linux all pipes are actually named pipes (i.e. they can be opened via a path). Using a regular named pipe, it will work on other Unix systems, too -- see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64148570/14223576) on Stackoverflow.

Comment: this is pretty cool! didn't know pipes could be used like this

Comment: @NordineLotfi Strictly speaking, it’s not anything special about pipes here. The magic is all in the `/dev/fd` paths. On (most) Linux systems, they’re special files that allow access to the file descriptors of the current process _in the context they are accessed from_. Not sure about the first example, but the second one works because the shell opens the fd for redirection before running the redirected command, and binds that to the requested fd in the command, which means that the shell’s fd 0 is being bound to fd 3 of the pipeline in the second example.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn 1. I don't know what you're trrying to say with "allow access ... in the context they are accessed from" -- I suspect that it's either some banal tautology or something horribly mistaken ;-)

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn 2. The shell opening `/dev/fd/0` has **nothing** to do with it whatsoever, it will work fine with the *original* awk even if `/dev/fd/0` was opened by awk: `echo hello | original-awk '!length{exit(0)} {print; print substr($0,2) >"/dev/fd/0"; fflush()}'`. In that example, I had to do the extra redirection for that silly example because GNU awk (gawk) has a kludge which handles some paths (like `/dev/fd/...`) internally, instead of passing them to the OS, even on OSs which support such paths.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with recursion:

```bsh
command1() {
  local var
  IFS= read -r var
  if [[ $var ]]; then
    printf '%s\n' "$var"
    cut -c2- <<< "$var" | "${FUNCNAME[0]}"
  fi
}
```

Then:

```
$ echo hello | command1
hello
ello
llo
lo
o
```

Comment: Recursion should be the correct answer here.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work:

```
foo() { [[ ! "${#1}" -eq 1 ]] && printf "%s" "$1" | cut -c2-; }

bar="hello"

while [[ ! -z $(foo "$bar") ]]; do bar=$(foo "$bar"); printf "%s\n" "$bar"; done

ello
llo
lo
o
```